# Unable to post comment on linkedin via API

Tags: javascript, php, linkedin-api

I want to post "comment" on linkedin post(dynamic),I am using following url but i dont know which information should be pass for post comment on linkedin post ? How can i do this ?
I tried with following url

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn}/comments
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a description of the required URL parameters, and the expected request body, and a sample in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/comments-api?view=li-lms-2022-12&tabs=http#create-a-comment
When you click the "curl" tab of the sample, you'll also see the HTTP headers.

Since you tagged this as PHP, you'll first want to create an array representing the POST body and encode that with JSON. You can then use the builtin curl support or via a package like GuzzleHTTP to send the actual POST request. Alternatively, there are [free and open-source packages](https://packagist.org/?query=linkedin) that implement easy-to-use wrappers around the LinkedIn API for use in PHP.